# How to properly write this JS script in PHP echo?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'd like to print this JS script.

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/inspinia/js/jquery-2.1.1.js'); ?>"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js'); ?>"></script>
```

I write like this:

```
print("<script type=\'text/javascript\' src=\'".base_url('assets/inspinia/js/jquery-2.1.1.js')."\'></script>");
print("<script type=\'text/javascript\' src=\'".base_url('assets/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js')."\'></script>");
```

and this:

```
echo "<script type=\'text/javascript\' src=\'".base_url('assets/inspinia/js/jquery-2.1.1.js')."\'></script>";
echo "<script type=\'text/javascript\' src=\'".base_url('assets/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js')."\"></script>";
```

But, both method can't get the external JS file.

Note: The `html` in in a modal

Comment: try this:-
`echo "<script type='text/javascript' src=' ".base_url('assets/inspinia/js/jquery-2.1.1.js')." '></script>";`

Comment: It's not called the JS. if I try to comment `//` the echo. It turn yellow until befor the `</script>`.

Comment: did you check the source when added the code like in comment? getting any error?

Comment: yes. using usual javascript it's called the js file. but using PHP echo, it's not.

Comment: not with usual script.. i am saying about code in comment. did you get any error when you try this code. check first comment

Comment: no errors. But my modal is messed up.

Comment: then it might be some issues with your model code

Answer (score 1):

To simplify, I will first give you an example with the url saved as a variable.

```
$url = base_url('assets/inspinia/js/jquery-2.1.1.js');

echo "<script src='$url'></script>";
```

You can keep it in the long form if you prefer, but you would need to leave the quotes and concatenate (similar to what you have been doing)

```
echo "<script src='" . base_url('assets/inspinia/js/jquery-2.1.1.js') . "'></script>";
```

For that reason, I always prefer to assign it to a variable first so that I can see the separation of "get value" and then "print string including that value"

Comment: It's calling the JS file. But it messed up my modal.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of using javascript in php echo:

```
<?php
echo '<script>Hello World!</script>';
?>
```

Comment: I need an example using the `base_url()`

Comment: check comment under OP

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit sorry to see what you mean, is that so?

```js
echo "<script  type='text/javascript'>
function getState(){            
        var cs = ".$state.";
        return cs;
} 
</script>";
```

Do you want to introduce JS files in PHP? 
You can wrap yourself,and you can refer to YII2's wording, like this：

```js
/**
 * 定义按需加载JS方法
 * @param $view View
 * @param $jsfile
 */
public static

function addScript($view, $jsfile) {
  $AssetManager = new AssetManager();
  $jsfile = $AssetManager - > getPublishedUrl('@backend/modules/motorcade/assets').$jsfile;
  $view - > registerJsFile($jsfile, [motorcadeUIAsset::className(), 'depends' => 'backend\modules\motorcade\assets\motorcadeUIAsset']);
}
```

Hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

> Try this,

```
echo "<script src=" '. base_url('assets/inspinia/js/jquery-2.1.1.js') .' "></script>";
```